# How do I remove "noatime" from a filesystem mount on macOS Monterey?

Tags: mac, filesystem, mount

I use access times ("atime") ... frequently.
Yesterday, I moved my MacMini to Monterey (from Catalina?), and now I see that the access time (atime) on files is not being updated when they are accessed.

My Mojave system works fine:

```
sf: ls -lu foo
-rw-r--r--  1 sieler  staff  64 Feb 27 13:20 foo
sf:$ cat foo
   foo is nearly empty 
sf: ls -lu foo
-rw-r--r--  1 sieler  staff  64 Feb 27 13:38 foo
```

We see that the atime has changed, as it should.

Some googles later...

On the Monterey system, a "mount" command shows fs volume (on Monterey) has the "noatime" attribute:

```
mount | grep atime
/dev/disk1s5 on /System/Volumes/VM (apfs, local, noexec, journaled, noatime, nobrowse)
```

Any suggestions on how to remove the "**noatime**" flag would be welcome.

thanks!

Stan

Comment: Why do you need to remove noatime on the swap volume?  Why do you care?

Comment: @MarcWilson I care because being able to know the access time *IS EXTREMELY* valuable in many cases.  For example, on Mojave, if my C code does "include <stdargs.h>", *WHAT FILE DID IT INCLUDE* (i.e., the entire path)?  There are dozens...and *none* (sigh, thanks, Apple!) under /usr/include!   If 'atime' worked, I'd check the atime of those dozens and know the secret path.  (That matters because I have tools that scan /usr/include for me)

Comment: Late comment... as I pointed out, noatime is being applied to the VM volume, not to your storage volume(s).  So look to something else as to why your access times do not update.

Comment: Any idea what the "something else" is?   My atime is being swallowed too.

Comment: @BryanLarsen check out https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/441754/how-does-file-access-time-updating-work-on-macos/448603?noredirect=1#comment700122_448603 ... there's a great comment by H.Katsura which solved the problem for me.  Basically, issuing a mount command adding "strictatime".